# Is there an np.arange fuction for matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to find a way to create a numpy array just like the np.arange(start,stop,step) but will let me shape the array a chosen 2D shape such as the line of the array will be the elements from 'start' to 'stop' and the columns will be repetition of the elements of that line. 
because doing that is not optimal;

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]).reshape(6,3)
```

Comment: Look at applying `np.repeat` to your `arange`.

Comment: Might consider [np.mgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) if you are using for building coordinates systems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of broadcasting, if you add your row (red in diagram) to a column (blue in diagram) of zeroes, you will also get what you want:

```
np.arange(0, 6) + np.zeros((3,1))
```

**Result**

```
 ([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
   [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
   [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]])
```

[image]

Hopefully you can see that broadcasting is filling in the dashes inside the arrays by repeating whatever you start off with, to fill out the `M` rows and `N` columns to become 2 `MxN` arrays which are then added together.

---

If you want your gradient running up-down instead of left-right, you need to reshape your incrementing row to a column before adding a row of zeroes:

```
np.arange(6).reshape(-1,1) + np.zeros((1,8))
```

**Result**

```
[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
[3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
[4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.],
[5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.]
```

---

And if you want to teach the kids their times tables :-)

```
np.arange(1,13).reshape(-1,1) * np.arange(1,13)
```

**Result**

```
[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12],
[  2,   4,   6,   8,  10,  12,  14,  16,  18,  20,  22,  24],
[  3,   6,   9,  12,  15,  18,  21,  24,  27,  30,  33,  36],
[  4,   8,  12,  16,  20,  24,  28,  32,  36,  40,  44,  48],
[  5,  10,  15,  20,  25,  30,  35,  40,  45,  50,  55,  60],
[  6,  12,  18,  24,  30,  36,  42,  48,  54,  60,  66,  72],
[  7,  14,  21,  28,  35,  42,  49,  56,  63,  70,  77,  84],
[  8,  16,  24,  32,  40,  48,  56,  64,  72,  80,  88,  96],
[  9,  18,  27,  36,  45,  54,  63,  72,  81,  90,  99, 108],
[ 10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100, 110, 120],
[ 11,  22,  33,  44,  55,  66,  77,  88,  99, 110, 121, 132],
[ 12,  24,  36,  48,  60,  72,  84,  96, 108, 120, 132, 144]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.repeat` as suggested by hpaulj, but you will need to add a new axis to the array created by `np.arange` first.

```
np.repeat(np.arange(0, 6)[np.newaxis,:], 3, axis=0)

# array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```